# Build failed error when trying to install ruby v 2.2.2 with rbenv on ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rbenv

I was trying to install ruby v2.2.2 after having installed rbenv but I got this error. I am pretty new to Ubuntu and Ruby and wanted to know if there was a way to fix this. Thank you.

```
BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 14.04 using ruby-build 20150818-4-g8d6ff29)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20150922205847.10469
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20150922205847.10469.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for gmp.h... no
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... 64
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking whether char is unsigned... no
checking for inline... no
checking for working volatile... no
checking for typeof syntax and keyword spelling... __typeof__
configure: error: ANSI C-conforming const and volatile are mandatory
```

I have also done the following, but to no avail:

```
udo apt-get install autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev         libreadline6 libreadline6-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by GCC version mismatch. You have GCC version that is "too new" for this particular Ruby version. Here's how to overcome this problem.

## rbenv

`CFLAGS="-O2 -fno-tree-dce -fno-optimize-sibling-calls" rbenv install [your-version]`

## rvm

`CFLAGS="-O2 -fno-tree-dce -fno-optimize-sibling-calls" rvm install [your-version]`

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to arise from missing packages.

This [article](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04) details how to "Setup Ruby On Rails on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr". Your question is answered in the "Installing Ruby" section of the article.

To begin, install **all** the dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev
```

Now you can use rbenv to install ruby:

```
rbenv install 2.2.2
```

Comment: I did that as well it still throws the same error message.